# LINQPad 4 unable to find EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad

I'm trying to use LINQPad 4 (the latest beta) with Entity Framework POCO classes. I take the normal path of creating a new connection and then selecting "Entity Framework DbContext POCO(4.1) and then selecting my he assembly holding my classes. When I do so I get the following message

"Could not load file or assembly EntityFramework. Version=4.1.O.O,
Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 or one of its dependencies.

The system cannot find the file specified."

I'm able to load the assembly from my application just fine. What gives? It seems a bit different from the previous problem like this reported in the CTP.

Comment: I just got the same error.  Can't figure out why.  Maybe the latest build is just broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem today, this is how I solved it:

Apparently the LINQPad 4.36.3 requires in some way Entity Framework 4.2 :/
It was released last week: [ADO.NET blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/01/ef-4-2-released.aspx)

What I did is:

1. Installed EF4.2 via NuGet
2. Rebuilt the project
3. Copied all my project .dll files to LINQPad folder (including the 4.2 EF.dll)
4. I read [here](http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/52061-problems-with-linqpad-and-ef42-codefirst/) that I need to add something to the LINQPad.exe.config file but it was already there.. 
   [At this point I tried removing that assembly redirect and ran it against my 4.1 dll, did not work, was still looking for 4.2]
5. Closed VS and uninstalled EF4.1

Thats it, after that both my project is now running on 4.2 and LINQPad works as well.

Comment: Thanks! I updated LINQPad and EF on Friday afternoon and was fairly bummed to see my POCO connections stop working. `Test` would return `Successful` in the connection's properties menu. And then it would bomb on the editor with the same error as above. Copying `EntityFramework.dll` locally to `LINQPad`'s directory seems to have fixed it.