# LINQPad can't find Entity Framework 4.3: Could not load file or assembly EntityFramework

Tags: linqpad, entity-framework-4.3, assembly-resolution

I'm trying to use LINQPad with my MVC3 project that is using Entity Framework 4.3. In LINQPad I create a new connection like this:
Add Connection -> Use A typed Data Context -> EF DBContext POCO
Point it to my assembly, provide full typename, reference web.config. Then try to test and see this error:
[image: LINQPad missing Entity Frameword]

I've installed EF via nuget, so it is not referenced in GAC. (I have tried that, I could not do it, don't think EF is GAC'able, but I could be wrong here). I've copied EntityFramework.dll into the same folder as LINQPad - no luck. Then added this to linqpad.exe.config

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

but no luck. Keep getting the same problem.
I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012431/linqpad-4-unable-to-find-entityframework) and been [here](http://forums.oreilly.com/topic/52061-problems-with-linqpad-and-ef42-codefirst/) - no luck.

Any other ideas??

p.s. I'm using EF 4.3, LINQPad 4.42.01. Just tried the latest LINQPad Beta and the same problem.

UPDATE: According to Joe, this problem is fixed in 4.42.5, at the moment available in Beta: www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx. Did have a go on it and it was indeed fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem, although I can't fix it because I can't reproduce it.

The workaround is here:
http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/21/does-linqpad-support-ef-4-3-1-now#latest

Comment: Joe, thanks for fixing the problem in 4.42.5. I can confirm, this issue is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem when using a LocalDb connection with the |DataDirectory| alias. Fixed by following Joe's suggestion to create a separate web.config with only the connection string, but also gave it an absolute path.